# use case include

Tags: architecture, uml, use-case

I have use case `order book`, when the user order a book he must browse the book ( use case `browse books`) then he must set the address to take the book (use case `set address`)
what is the relationship between the two usecases with `order book` usecase?

```
Include ?
Extend?
Something Else?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.

Don't get down to high resolution with use-cases, they are supposed to be high level items (e.g., consider removing `set address` use-case by adding its functionality to another, probably `order book`). The relationship in case of **must** will be `include`. In case it's optional, the relation will be `extend`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i asked two more questions 3 hours ago but no one has answered , would u please check them